# codeigniter and redirecting on expired urls

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a site built with codeigniter. Everything is working great except, I have a news area with a setof pages that disappear after a set amount of time. When people access the old links I want to redirect them to a different page. The rub is the links are www.site.com/controller/function/page-id-with-numbers-0098468854. If someone accesses the link it works great. What i would like to route away is mistyped page ids and deleted ids redirect to a sorry page moved page, or better yet homepage with an alert or message.

Comment: do deleted id pages get a 404?

Comment: unfortunately not as of right now it tries to load the news page just without the db variables available

Comment: OK, then I suppose Bora's answer is the correct one. Coz, you can just check the ID against your DB and have the page redirect if it doesn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `show_404()` CI Document [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html)

At first, parse uri segment with this and get page ID

```
$this->uri->segment(n);
```

Check DB page id exist or not and show 404 page like below:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
   show_404();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Was half way there with my sql query, just didnt get to the uri class myself.